# Add a class to a div where partial match of attribute value doesn't match any values in separate array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Say I have the following array of divs which I've assigned to a var `fileTypes`

```
<dd data-param-type="facetFilters" data-param-value="document_type:pdf">PDFs</dd>
<dd data-param-type="facetFilters" data-param-value="document_type:document">Documents</dd>
<dd data-param-type="facetFilters" data-param-value="document_type:spreadsheet">Spreadsheets</dd>
<dd data-param-type="facetFilters" data-param-value="document_type:presentation">Presentations</dd>
<dd data-param-type="facetFilters" data-param-value="document_type:image">Images</dd>
```

And I also have the following Object:

```
{email: 80, pdf: 27}
```

What's the best way to loop through the `fileTypes` divs and add a class of `disabled` if their `data-param-value` matches neither `email` or `pdf`?

I'm using the following to extract the param-value after the :

```
var type = $(item).data('param-value');
var regex = /type:(.*)/;
var match = regex.exec(type);
console.log(match[1]);
=> pdf // (document, spreadsheet, etc)
```

What I can't quite solve is a clean way to find the divs that don't contain a match. I've taken a crack at `_.filter` and `_.difference` in Underscore, but am unable to get it right.

Comment: If you're okay with jQuery answers, add jQuery tag and/or mention the same in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using jQuery, so it's `filter` method can be used for filtering the matching elements:

```
// get the object keys
var keys = Object.keys({email: 80, pdf: 27});

$('dd[data-param-value]').filter(function() {
   var key = $(this).data('param-value').split(':')[1];
   return $.inArray(key, keys) === -1;
}).addClass('disabled');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vxduagky/